# git directory is not available in docker container for the nested project

Tags: git, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-devcontainer

I have the following structure of the project

```
  - project/
    .git
    - backend/
         docker-compose.yaml
         Dockerfile
    - assets
    - documentation
```

I do deployment of the `backend` sub-project only, because this is where my Docker files and the source code are.

I'm using VS Code and developing it in the running container (thanks to the Dev containers feature in VS Code). However, Git capabilities in this case are not available. That's because the .git directory is in the project root and I deploy only the nested project.

What would be the best solution to have git enabled in the running container (for development purposes only)? Should I copy the entire root directory in the Docker container?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for git submodules.

That way, your backend can have its own seperate repo that you can use normally from the deployment.

When you add a repository as a submodule, in the parent's environment it just looks like a subfolder, so your directory structure up top won't at all change.

Little tip: submodules always point to just one commit, not a branch. This takes some getting used to, but it is really helpful for reproducibility.

### Deployment steps

- create a new repo with just the backend
- copy all the stuff from your current backend directory to that repo
- delete the backend directory from the current project
- run `git submodule add <new-repo-url> ./backend`